# Using LabelEncoder for a series in scikitlearn

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a Column in a Dataset which has categorical values and I want to convert them in Numerical values. I am trying to use LabelEncoder but get errors doing so.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
m = hsp_train["Alley"]
m_enc = LabelEncoder()
j = m_enc.fit_transform(m)
```

I am getting an error:

> unorderable types: float() > str()

The series in the Column has 3 values. I want them to be 0, 1, 2 respectively but I am getting that error.

I also tried this:

```
l = hsp_train["Alley"]
l_enc = pd.factorize(l)
hsp_train["Alley"] = l_enc[0]
```

But this is giving me values -1, 1, 2. which I don't want I want it from 1.

Comment: From what I know OneHotEncoder is useful for integers I suppose and pandas.get_dummies increases the number of columns which I dont want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's obviously clear that you have missing values in your series. If you want to remove `NaN` values from your series, just do `hsp_train["Alley"].dropna()`

**Illustration:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Categorical': ['apple', 'mango', 'apple', 
                                   'orange', 'mango', 'apple', 
                                   'orange', np.NaN]})
```

Using `LabelEncoder` to encode the categorical labels:

```
enc = LabelEncoder()
enc.fit_transform(df['Categorical'])
```

Gives:

> TypeError: unorderable types: float() > str()

Doing `pd.factorize` automatically assigns -1 to missing values by default and hence you get those values:

```
pd.factorize(df['Categorical'])[0]
array([ 0,  1,  0,  2,  1,  0,  2, -1])
```

---

If you do not want `NAN` values to be identified and to consider them just as any string, you can do it while reading process using `na_filter`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(data, na_filter=False, ...)
```

It also improves the performance of reading a relatively large file drastically.

---

Or, you could fill all the `NaN` values using `fillna` to the desired string of your choice:

```
df.fillna('Na', inplace=True)
```

This replaces all the `NaN` values to your string value "Na" and you can continue as before.

Comment: Thank you @Nickil for the explanation, but what if I want that missing value which is actually a category described as "Na" (pandas is taking it as a NaN value) to be a third category ?